# Best way to keep data in cache across mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

In my application I have a list of schools that can be read off a database table.  I want to use this list in many places in my website such as the registration form, different drop downs across my site etc.  What is the best way to keep track of this data if it does not change often,  I was thinking of storing it in cache, but at what point in the application do I load that cache?  Also do I use dependency injection and create some custom class that retrieves this data?  The data set is not large, its at most 20 or so schools.

Comment: Have you looked at `System.Runtime.Caching`?

Comment: If it is such a small data set then the overhead of retrieving it when you need it is minimal.   Storing it in cache adds a whole new set of challenges like server restarts, browser crashes etc.  If you do decide to keep it in cache, look at system.runtime.caching as Serg posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use dependency injection and the repository pattern.  The injection would be done once per session as it is created.  This is when the repository is created and stored as a singleton class that could then be injected into each page that needs it.

As the repository is created, you could do one read to the data store to get your list of schools, and load it into an internal list.

There are some excellent articles here on [implementing IOC in MVC](http://blog.ploeh.dk/SearchView.aspx?q=mvc%20injection) that should start you on your way.

As for the repository pattern, there are many different ways of implementing it, just do a [Google](http://goo.gl/zzSVo) search.

Answer (score 0):

Its pure design decision how you want to maintain the cache, based on your requirement you have take the call. You can load these data into application object / cache object during application start event in global.aspx

Refer this

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-in-the-architecture-cs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd129907.aspx